# ag-grid vs Kendo React grid pros and cons

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, kendo-ui, ag-grid

I was wondering what your opinion is on choosing the right tool for implementing a grid in my react project? It should support paging, filtering, adding new data, editing the existing data (in a new view). I already know that all two options support all the things I need, but I have 0 experience in all of them. So I was wondering, which one do you think is best?

Answer (score 6):

**ag-Grid: Absolute winner!** It is feature rich, good looking and well documented.

The below link has explained the Rendering Time, Frames Per Second (FPS), Memory Consumption, Live Updates capacity in detail.

https://www.crankuptheamps.com/blog/posts/2020/01/23/grid-comparison-2/#

You can check the popularity of different grid in the below link

https://jspreadsheets.com/

From experience I can say ag grid has the best documentation so the learning and implementation will be easy. The documentation is so good that you can learn to implement all the features in just one day.

Size-wize, ag-Grid is larger than much of the competition. This may be a deal-breaker for some people.

Comment: Agree totally with this - ag-Grid is the way to go.  But I would add that you should integrate with AdapTable.  We do that and the combined power of the 2 components together is awesome.